# How can we use an existing taglib functionality within our custom tags?

Tags: java, jsp, taglib

Though I'm not new to taglib creation but I am confused as to how we can use an existing tag definition within my own custom tag?

I am writing a taglib to encapsulate a jsp code snippet which is used regularly within jsp files. But that snippet contains other struts tag like **,**  etc.

I have to encapsulate all of this in one single **custom** tag.

Is it possible that I can make use of struts taglib classes directly or what else?

Please suggest how I should proceed.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight-forward. Create the JSP code snippets that you want in your taglib. Store them somewhere (typically seems to be `WEB-INF\tags`, but could be `\templates`). File names should end with .tag. Tell the JSP compiler where the snippets are:

```
<%@taglib prefix="template" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
```

and use them

```
<template:_name_of_template_file_without_extension_/>
```

where you just reference the file. 
There is the alternative syntax for template, but then you are not making a taglib.

```
<template:insert template = "String" [ base = "String" ] [ id = "" ] [ locale = "" ] > 
...Body Content...
</template:insert>
```

Excuse me, if you want to create your own taglib

```
<%@taglib uri="_filename_.tld" prefix="_lib_prefix_" %>
```

then use it

```
<_lib_prefix_:_lib_tag_ _WHATEVER_/>
```

Finally, you can use an existing taglib within the custom tags

Comment: i guess you are asking me to create a custom tag file.

Comment: Well, I tried to show that there are several ways to do this; it depends really what your goal is. 1) custom tag file, 2) a template, or 3) really your own taglib. What's your goal?

Comment: what i need is a way to use struts tags say <s:iterate> inside my custom taglib definition.